# Bash printf sequence with interactive input

Tags: command-line, bash

In bash how to get `printf` take input interactively to print a sequence. I have tried the following:

```
read x; read y; printf '%s\n' {"$x".."$y"..5}
0
40
{0..40..5}
```

whence I am trying to get the output like this:

```
printf '%s\n' {0..40..5}
0
5
10
15
20
25
30
35
40
```

Comment: @user535733 Shell scripting questions are on-topic in AskUbuntu and, as such, they should not be closed as off-topic. Please read this meta post: [Are bash/shell scripting questions on topic?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13807/are-bash-shell-scripting-questions-on-topic?answertab=votes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you can't use variables that way in a bash brace expansion.

Instead, you can use `seq`:

```
read x; read y; printf '%d\n' $(seq "$x" 5 "$y")
```

or more straightforwardly

```
read x; read y; seq "$x" 5 "$y"
```

or a C-style `for` loop:

```
read x; read y; for ((i=x;i<=y;i+=5)); do printf '%d\n' "$i"; done
```

See for example

- [How can I use $variable in a shell brace expansion of a sequence?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/how-can-i-use-variable-in-a-shell-brace-expansion-of-a-sequence)